# An EditTextPreference with Minimum character requirement

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, preferences

I have an `EditTextPreference` that I user to allow use to set a passcode to an app.  I want to require a 4-digit passcode.  I set the `maxLength = "4"` in the xml file.  Now I have the problem to not allow submit unless the entered passcode is 4 digits long.

Here is what I have:

```
 <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue=""
            android:dependency="EnablePasscode"
            android:dialogMessage="Add a numeric passcode to provide access to enter the app.  The passcode must be 4 digits."
            android:dialogTitle="Set Passcode"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:key="passcode"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:password="true"
            android:title="Set Passcode" />
```

Now in Java:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {

    if (key.equals("passcode")) {
        EditTextPreference setPasscode = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("passcode");
        if (setPasscode.getText().toString().length() == 4) {
            // return true
        }
    }

}
```

Where it says `return true` comment out, I am not sure how to handle this;  I know I don't do a `return`; what I want it it to submit the Dialog Box if length is 4, otherwise if it is 0, 1, 2, or 3, throw a `toast`.  Where and how can I do that?

**UPDATE**:  TO validate this preference, I need control of the OK button which I do not have; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245069/how-to-setonclicklistener-to-ok-button-of-an-edittextpreference-dialog) may be a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private EditTextPreference preference;

this.preference = ((EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen() //put this in the onCreate                
                .findPreference("passcode"));

  if (key.equals("passcode")) {
        EditTextPreference setPasscode = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("passcode");
        if (sharedPreferences.getString("passcode","0").length() != 4) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Should be 4 digits", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           this.preference.setText(null);
           return;
        }else{
              Toast.makeText(this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
    }
```

something like this should help you. Do keep in mind that `getPreferenceScreen` is deprecated, it is recommended to use `PreferenceFragment`. I am assuming that `PreferenceActivity` is being extended here.

Comment: That is close, but when you press the OK `button` in the `dialog`, it still does submit (the toasts are accurate though).  I think the key is getting control of that OK button which is probably different then `EditTextPreference` which is more for the `EditText` view.

Comment: I dont see any dialog in the xml. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: With `EditTextPreference`, what it does when user clicks on it in Settings, it opens up a `dialog` with the `EditText` field, and two buttons: OK and Cancel.  I didn't program this; it is default behavior in the xml.  I think in the Java I have to find a way to access control of the `Button` for it.

Comment: I changed the answer. Try and see if it works for you

Comment: this.preference.setText(null); add this line to the code. Check the answer

Comment: Well if I enter 4 characters and hit OK, it closes fine;  If I hit less than 4, I get a `NullPointer` on this line:  `if (setPasscode.getText().toString().length() != 4) {`, with I'm assuming `setPasscode` is the culprit.

Comment: according to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527894/how-to-call-the-ok-button-in-the-edittextpreference) , what I need can't be done with this method.  I may need to make a custom preference.

Comment: Ok the last edit didn't crash it, but the dialog still closes.  Still not sure we can access control of that button.   Though this guy says this method worked but I'm not so sure .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024692/android-validating-routine-for-edittextpreference

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44077/discussion-between-user2511882-and-kickinglettuce)